# Make linear layout spread icons evenly without stretching the icons

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a horizontal linear layout. with 4 image buttons. I want to distribute these evenly of the width of the screen.

Normally I would do this by setting the layout widths of the icons to 0dp, and weights to 1. Then I would set the the linear layout wight sum to 4 as below.

However when I do this it stretches the button.

How do you distribute them evenly without icon stretching and without having to use a relative layout and set margins?

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:weightSum="4">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mainAlarmButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_alarm_white_18dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addAlarmButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_add_white_18dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/shareButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_share_white_18dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_tune_white_18dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: use wrap_content for width instead of 0dp

Comment: stretches the button because of Image size, set different image for different screen size.

Comment: Just thinking out loud: if these are image buttons, so is the size of the image correct according to what you want after the spread? Have you tried creating the ui in a photo editing software like photoshop? I don't know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the responses. They are material icons downloaded from the google site. They are the correct size on wrap content for material guidelines. @masoudvali thanks it still stretches them though. Not as bad but a little.

Comment: so just use a number for their width base on your icon's size

Comment: Ok thanks, I was trying to avoid that but guess I will have to

Comment: all you need is to replace `android:background` with `android:src`

Comment: @pskink  Awesome that was it thank you!

Comment: sure, you are welcome, but you dont have to use `ImageView` as shadoWalker says since `ImageButton` extends `ImageView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `ImageView` instead of `ImageButton`, then instead of `android:background` use `android:src`. Then with using proper `android:scaleType` you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: no need to switch to `ImageView` since `ImageButton` extends `ImageView`

Comment: I have suggested that because of background problems that ImageButton causes.

Answer (score 1):

Use dummy Views in between your ImageButtons

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="5"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mainAlarmButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_alarm_white_18dp"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/addAlarmButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_add_white_18dp"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/shareButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_share_white_18dp"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_tune_white_18dp"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but, that seems like a large memory waste